# InputStream, BufferedImage missing images

Tags: java, image, parsing, http

I am trying to parse images from a url. It is working fine.
But i also want to get height and width of images.
So, I am trying to use `BufferedImage`.

But if I try to make any type of connection with images, it starts skipping images.
I do not know why this happening, may be for loop forcing to skip large images.

Code - >

```
public Vector getimages(Document doc) {
    Vector images = new Vector(50, 50);
    Elements png = doc.select("img");

    try {

        BufferedImage readImage_img = null;
        for(Element pngs : png) {
           if(!images.contains(new String(pngs.attr("abs:src")))) {
             //InputStream is = new URL(pngs.attr("abs:src")).openStream();

             //readImage_img = ImageIO.read(is);
             //int img_h = readImage_img.getHeight();
             //int img_w = readImage_img.getWidth();
             //if(img_h>50 && img_w>50)
             //{
             images.addElement(new String(pngs.attr("abs:src")));
             //}
           } 
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return images;
}
```

But if I uncomment inputstream or buffer it skips images mainly large.

Comment: Try printing the exception in the empty catch block

Comment: Got it thanx
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://im.tech2.in.com/

Comment: Is that really the full URL? That's just a domain name, so it can't be an image URL.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 error means forbidden. This could mean that either the URL is wrong, double-encoded, or is right but something else is wrong. You probably need to set the `User-Agent` HTTP header to pretend that your program is a web browser.